# Button Click Event not working

Tags: javascript

I just write some JS code for click listener, if a button is clicked more than 5 times in 3 seconds then alert will say you wan otherwise you lost.
But I am getting every time **YOU LOST!!**

```
<head>  
</head>
<body>
<button>Click!!</button>
<script>
    let counter =0;
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('Click', () => {
        counter++;
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        if(counter > 5) {
            alert('You Won!!' + counter);
        } else {
            alert('You Lost!!' + counter);
        }
    },3000)
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: yes but it need to be outside

Comment: Change "Click" to "click" (small case) in `addEventListener('click', () => {})`

Answer (score 1):

you may use lowercase 'click' not 'Click', you didn't call your click event anytime in your sample code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

Answer (score 1):

Minor change on your source code. Now working fine.

```js
 let counter =0;

    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () =>counter++);

    setTimeout(() => {
        if(counter > 5) {
            alert('You Won!!' + counter);
        } else {
            alert('You Lost!!' + counter);
        }

    },3000)
```

```css
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<button>Click!!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kuzp57y2/)

**I changed "Click" to "click", small case only.**
`addEventListener('click', () => {})`

Might want to check out : [JavaScript event listeners are case sensitive.](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2010/08/html-event-handlers-and-javascript-event-listeners/)

```
<button>Click!!</button>
<script>
    let counter =0;
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        counter++;
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        if(counter > 5) {
            alert('You Won!!' + counter);
        } else {
            alert('You Lost!!' + counter);
        }
    },3000)
</script>
```

Result :

LOST :

[image: Lost]

WON :

[image: WON]

Comment: 'Click' vs 'click'?

Comment: I changed "Click" to "click", small case only.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code, two things I noticed were you used an uppercase for your click event:

```
addEventListener('Click'
```

and I also changed the if to alert 'you won' if counter was greater than or equal to 5

```
if(counter >= 5)
```

Here's a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fkvvc1f0/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use external JavaScript and CSS, for caching reasons, but I think you want to see this:

```
function lameGame(clickElement){
  let c = 0;
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(c > 5) {
      alert('You Won!!' + c); // never use alert in real world
    }
    else{
      alert('You Lost!!' + c); // never use alert in real world
    }
    lameGame(clickElement);
  }, 3000);
  clickElement.onclick = function(){
    c++;
  }
}
lameGame(document.querySelector('button'));
```